# MomentJS max and min return wrong values

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I've encountered a strange result when comparing two MomentJS objects using max and min methods. They appear to return the wrong value.
For example, this code returns today rather than tomorrow:

```
moment().max(moment().add(1, 'd'))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cGtbY/

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: Anyone looking up this question should take note that moment.js 2.7.0+ has a new [max function](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/max/) that works similarly to `Math.max`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking in the source code of MomentJS 2.2.1, here's the source code of max():

```
max: function ( other ) {
    other = moment.apply( null, arguments );
    return other > this ? this : other;
},
```

Seems like they are returning `this` when `other` is later.. Weird..

Comment: Looks like you're right, Ephi. I've opened an issue in Github for this.

Answer (score 2):

You misinterpret the meaning of `min` and `max`.

From the test suite (https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/test/moment/min_max.js#L51):

```
    equalMoment(test, now.max(future), now,   "Now with the maximum of the future should be now");
```

The way to understand the meaning is: `a.max(b) <= b` (at latest, the result can be the second date).

The documentation has a clear quote:

> Sometimes, server clocks are not quite in sync with client clocks.  This ends up displaying humanized strings such as "in a few seconds" rather than "a few seconds ago". You can prevent that with moment#max()

The `.max` function is therefore the numerical minimum (selecting the earlier moment)

Comment: I interpreted the documentation at http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/max/ rather than the test suit when I used the code. It explicitly states that max will return the later of the moments. From the issue I've opened in Github, I got that they consider it a bug in the documentation, but it's still a problem, and still counter-intuitive. But kuddos for voting down my question and Ephi's answer. This proves you know better.

Comment: I really do not understand what is the meaning of `min()` and `max()` if `a.max(b) <= b`.
What is the use of max in this case?

Comment: @yarons The documentation for max reads 'This ends up displaying humanized strings such as "in a few seconds" rather than "a few seconds ago". You can prevent that with moment#max()', which clearly means that max is returning the earlier and not the later date.

Comment: From the documentation: Note: moment#max doesn't actually mutate the moment; it sim(p)ly returns the input moment if the input moment is later, and this otherwise.